# MongoDb's C# Drivers, is it possible to wrap it in a generic session?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm apologizing if I'm using the wrong terminology here. I'm still very much in the ORM world, but I've been playing around with MongoDb and really love what I see. One of the things I'm not liking is this:

```
var books = bookRepository.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("books");
```

And

```
foreach (var book in books.FindAllAs<Book>())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Author: {0}, Title: {1}", book.Author, book.Title);
}
```

I've found several tutorials on wrapping [NoRM in a session](http://lukencode.com/2010/07/09/getting-started-with-mongodb-and-norm/) but I can't figure out how to do it using the CSharp Drivers (the ones that Mongodb recommends / has on their github page).

What I'd really like to do is something like this for the first example:

```
var bookRepository = MongoRepository<Book>(); // probably should use IoC to resolve this
```

and

```
foreach (var book in books.FindAll())
```

Voila! I'm probably not the first person to want this, using strings everywhere seems a bit nutty, though I will grant that the tutorial is just an example. Is there a "best practices" example to setting this all up in such a manner?

Edit: Please let me know if this is crazy talk and not how to do things in Mongo, again this is my first test project.

Comment: What are you asking for, exactly? In ORMs you still need to configure the ORM so that it knows which object is stored in which table; this forces you to have strings. You can certainly move the string with the collection name from the "get repository" call to a "configure repositories" step, akin to Fluent Nhibernate's mappings.

Answer (score 6):

Here is snippet from my project:

```
public static MongoCollection<T> GetCollection<T>(string collectionName = null)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(collectionName))
    {
        Type g = typeof (T);
        collectionName = g.Name;
    }
    return MongoServer.Create(Config.MongoConnectionString).GetDatabase(Config.Database).GetCollection<T>(collectionName);
}
```

Now I dont need to specify a collection name as a string unless I want to override it:

```
var collection = GetCollection<MyEntity>();
```

or

```
var collection = GetCollection<MyEntity>("SomeOtherCOllection");
```

You can use some inflection utility\library to pluralize your collection names if you want.

Also, you dont need to specify the type in your `Find` methods if you specified the type when instantiating a collection class, like I have above.

For example, this is how I do it:

```
MongoCursor<MyEntity> results = collection.FindAll();
```

or

```
MongoCursor<MyEntity> results = collection.Find(query);
```

Comment: I'm in the process of creating a generic Mongo DAL class.  Do you by chance have other methods like your GetCollection<T> method for CRUD ops that you'd be willing to share?

Comment: @JeffBorden Sorry I don't. Most of the CRUD was specific to each task.